# ceph unable to increase pool pg_num

Tags: storage

I am using ceph 14.2.1 (Nautilus)

I am unable to increase the pg_num of a pool.

I have a pool named Backup, the current pg_num is 64 : ceph osd pool get Backup pg_num => result pg_num: 64

And when I try to increase it using the command

ceph osd pool set Backup pg_num 512 => result "set pool 6 pg_num to 512"

And then I check with the command : ceph osd pool get Backup pg_num => result pg_num: 64

I don't how to increase the pg_num of a pool, I also tried the autoscale module, but it doesn't work (unable to activate the autoscale, always warn mode).

Thank you for your help,

Cabeur.

Answer (score 1):

You must also increase the `pgp_num` of that pool (see [official documentation](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/operations/placement-groups/#set-the-number-of-placement-groups))

```
ceph osd pool set Backup pgp_num 512
```